Why does the hover information stop calculating?
In simple cases I find the hover information for variable types to calculate intuitively.  For example:
link to playground
type AB = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}

type A = Omit<AB, 'a'>
// hover over A to find it is calculated to be '{ b: 2 }'

however for more complicated cases such as a function returning a function - that same calculation seems to be left incomplete.  For example
link to playground
const omitKey = <K extends string>(key: K) =>
    <V extends Record<string, any>>(val: V): Omit<V, K> => {
        const result = {} as V
        for (const k of Object.keys(val) as (keyof V)[]) {
            if (!Object.hasOwn(val, k)) {
                result[k] = val[k]
            }
        }
        return result
    }

type AB = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}
const ab: AB = { a: 1, b: 2 }

const result = omitKey('a')(ab)
// hover over result to find it is calculated to be 'Omit<AB, "a">', not '{ b: 2 }'

Is this a limitation in typescript ?  Or is there something I can do to make the resulting type calculate as I expect ?

It's the same in vscode - which I assume the code is the same.  Feels to me it has to do with their type resolution algorithm rather than some code per-client

Oh, I thought you were asking about only the playground; but you're actually asking about the TypeScript Language Server (LSP), right? Are you using a recent release? It isn't getting bogged-down with a huge node_modules directory or anything? Have you enable LSP logging+diagnostics?

yeah the most recent release - don't think it has anything to do with a huge node_modules.  I wasn't aware of LSP logging+diagnostics - thanks for the lead.  I'll dig into that tomorrow and hopefully come up with something.

This (highly upvoted) QA suggests that it might be some other dodgy extension in your editor/IDE - so try disabling all other extensions (except TypeScript, of course) and seeing if that works.

It's not a limitation, it's working as intended. TypeScript chooses how to display types based on heuristics. See linked q/a above for more info. If you use a hand-rolled Omit equivalent then you'll see the type you expect, as shown in this playground link

Thanks much for the links and the quick solution @jcalz.  I'll handroll my own like you showed.
